# calling Firestore storage causing app to halt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I think in my code I'm somehow looping through the images but my console.log does insane. I have only 3 images in each folder. One called `back` and the other one called `front`. How can I have it display all images without causing the app to come to a crawling halt. Again they are only 3 images in each folder.

For sake of being concise I'm only going to post one of them.

```
   const [frontImage, setFrontImage] = useState();


    const getFrontImage = async () => {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

// like this right here gets put out almost 50 times
        console.log(user + "this is name");
        const imageRefs = await firebase.storage().ref().child(user + '/FrontPic/').listAll();
        const urls = await Promise.all(imageRefs.items.map((ref) => ref.getDownloadURL()));
        setFrontImage(urls);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        getFrontImage();
    });
```

**later on calling the images here**

```
              <View style={styles.DisplayImageWith}> 
                    {frontImage && frontImage.map(url => (
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} key={url}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: url }} style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} />
                    </View>
                    ))}
                </View>
```

Comment: Try to create minimal reproducible example before posting here. I think this is nothing to do with firestore at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `setFrontImage` call in `getFrontImage` causes another redner, which causes infinite loop.

If you want to run `getFrontImage`  only once, pass an empty array to useEffect like this: `useEffect(cb, [])`

Comment: thank you! For future knowledge, if you wanted to run getFrontImage at an interval I would have to create a function that does that and pass that into useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

Add a dependency array to the `useEffect` hook, which should include the function `getFrontImage`, therefore wrap it in a `useCallback` hook. You can also go with an empty dependency array `[]`